# ASP.NET MVC API - Authentication with username, password and one other field

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, authentication

I have an ASP.NET API that uses basic authentication to authenticate user requests. A new design requirement means I now have to authenticate with 3 fields (not just the username and password).

What is the best way to approach this? I've tried inserting the third field into the body and reading it on request. This works, but it feels wrong. Is there a way in which the third field could be part of the authorization header?

EDIT

I added the third field to the username (delimited with '|'). A HTTP module decodes and splits the header upon arrival, thus allowing for 3 field request authentication. Simple solution.

Comment: It's WebApi Right? You can use Claim based authentication to have more information as part of authentication process.

Comment: @RobH My apologies, I just meant 'body', ignore the 'HTML'. I'm editing that out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the third field into another header.  Or use some sort of delimiter and concatenate your third field into the auth header.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add anything else into the Header - you're only allowed *username*:*password* (Base64 encoded). You can add an additional header or include the data in request body.

Basic authentication isn't exactly practical - particularly for something like a JavaScript application running in a browser. You'll end up having to proxy the API on the server because you'd otherwise leak the credentials to anyone who knows how to open the browser dev tools.

I'd look at securing your API with a token based approach. E.g. JWT or OAuth.